# My GPU does not show up in CUDA

Tags: rendering, gpu, error

I have been looking around on the internet for a long while now, and I haven't gotten any info about this problem.

I have a NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 in my computer, but when I try to use it for cycles rendering, it doesn't show up in the CUDA tab at system, user preferences.

I am using Blender 2.8, if that may contribute. It just says "No compatible GPUs found for path tracing Cycles will render on the CPU"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to those in advance.

Comment: Under Preferences > System > CUDA, does your GPU show up there, and is the tick-box checked?

Comment: If your GPU is a GT 710 and not a GT 710M, then it should be supported. Try to [update your graphics driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156281/en-us) and check if that resolves the problem. Also make sure that your operating system recognizes the GPU, e.g. by checking `dxdiag` on Windows.